# I have to requirement to replace characters in file after "|^#" patterns. How can i do

Tags: unix, sed

I have a requirement to replace characters after `"|^#"` pattern in file .

How can i do so using "`Sed`" UNIX command?
My sample file will be like

```
    11~^6~^BRD_ACT_EVT_MG~^2017-11-29
21~^EVENT_ID~^SUBJECT~^TOPIC~^SENDER_PARTY_ID~^LANGUAGE~^ORIG_CHANNEL_CD~^CREATE_TS
782~^201711082887~^Br~^GEN~^AC1~^EN~^MB~^29-NOV-17 09.11.47.731000 AM|^#~1
782~^201771082877~^test~^GEN~^AC3~^EN~^MB~^29-NOV-17 02.38.16.386000 AM|^#~2
99~^6~^BRD_ACT_EVT_MG~^05:23:41~^2
```

The output should be :

```
    11~^6~^BRD_ACT_EVT_MG~^2017-11-29
21~^EVENT_ID~^SUBJECT~^TOPIC~^SENDER_PARTY_ID~^LANGUAGE~^ORIG_CHANNEL_CD~^CREATE_TS
782~^201711082887~^Br~^GEN~^AC1~^EN~^MB~^29-NOV-17 09.11.47.731000 AM|^#
782~^201771082877~^test~^GEN~^AC3~^EN~^MB~^29-NOV-17 02.38.16.386000 AM|^#
99~^6~^BRD_ACT_EVT_MG~^05:23:41~^2
```

Comment: Please put samples in CODE TAGS in `{}` button and show sample output too in your post.

Comment: Process requested by RavinderSingh13 by editing your question. If you have tried a couple of different methods to solve it post a few tries. This shows effort and is well appreciated by others and motivates to help you more than just blunt "I need help.. and provides rubbish we have to sort first".

Comment: Added sample file content in {}

Comment: @kiransai, I have added solution(s) please check once and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove only `|^#` then following may help you on same:

```
sed 's/|^#//g'  Input_file
```

In case you want to remove everything from `|^#` to till end of the line then then following may help you on same:

```
sed 's/|^#.*//'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I am new to unix & stackoverflow community. I have edited the sample just now. I want to remove characters after "|^#" using sed. But "|^#" pattern have to retain in the file content post prasing using sed

Comment: Not sure why for a simple answer I can get a -ve totally discouraging :(

Comment: Sorry mistakenly I have voted. Now i cannot able to change the voting.

Comment: I am getting this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputatation.but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". I will delete this post and re-post again

Comment: @kiransai cannot be the downvoter, since they do not have rep enough to do so.